# scipy.interpolate.interp1d folding map

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I am plotting the result of an interpolation in a periodic domain, namely, the earth mercator projection map, [0,2*pi] or [0,360] is the domain for  longitude. As you can see on the picture below, I'm plotting a groundtrack.

[image]

I am getting first `r`, i.e. position, and then I'm projecting that right onto earth. Since the coordinate transformations involves trigonometric functions, the results that I obtain are certainly restricted to a domain, where the inverse is bijective. To obtain this plot I've used `atan2` in order to obtain a non bijective inverse function, as well as manipulating `arccos` in order to extend the domain of the inverse function.

All good up to now. The fact is that when I interpolate the resulting points, naturally, the function that returns does not interpret the *domain folding* property.

I just wanted to know if there is any way around this, apart from manipulating my data and representing it in a non periodic domain, interpolate it, and after that applying `%(2*np.pi)`. These option, even if is doable, implies touching even more those inverse functions. The other option I thought was interpolating in chunks of only increasing values, i.e. and concatenating them.

Nothing found on the scipy documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue implementing something like the following. Notice that I am using `astropy` units module.

```
adder = 2*np.pi*u.rad
for i in range(1,len(lons)):
    if lons[i].value-lons[i-1].value > 1:
        sgn=np.sign(lons[i].value-lons[i-1].value)
        lons[i:] -= sgn*adder
```

after doing this, apply the `%`

```
f_lons = interp1d(t,lons)
lons = f_lons(new_t) % (2*np.pi)
```